# Implementing an interface in f#

Tags: c#, interface, f#, c#-to-f#

Here is my c# interface:

```
public interface ITemplateService
{
    string RenderTemplate(object model, string templateName);
    string RenderTemplate(object model, string templateName, string directory);
}
```

I'm trying to make an implementation in F# but got an error on the keyword `end`. (unexpected `end` in implementation file)

```
module TemplateService

open DotLiquid

type TemplateService = 
    inherit ITemplateService

        member this.RenderTemplate model (templateName:string):string = ""
        member this.RenderTemplate model (templateName:string, directory:string):string = ""
end//error here.
```

ps. What is this code in F#:

```
Template template = Template.Parse(stringToTemplate);
template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(model));
```

Comment: The "F# Fundamentals" tab here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/cc835246 has some good syntax links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to ChaosPandion's answer:

A class can either be defined like this:

```
type ClassName(constructorArguments) =
  class
    ...
  end
```

or like this:

```
type ClassName(constructorArguments) =
  ...
```

So you need either both the `class` and the `end` keyword or none of them. Usually people use the form 
without `class` and `end`.

Your other code snippet would look something like this:

```
let template = Template.Parse stringToTemplate
template.Render (Hash.FromAnonymousObject model)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are implementing an interface you'll want to use this syntax.

```
type TemplateService() = 
    interface ITemplateService with
        member this.RenderTemplate model (templateName:string):string = ""
        member this.RenderTemplate model (templateName:string, directory:string):string = ""
```